Low Quality from Elgato Cam Link 4k (USB Capture Card) in Vuforia
i would like to do an AR Image tracking with the source of an DJI Drone. For this i bought an Elgato Cam Link4k USB Capture card. If i connect it via USB to the drone, i can open it in Windows with a clean, high res image.
Now, i selected the device in Vuforia as "PlayMode Type" > Webcam and "Camera Device" > Cam Link 4k, the image resulotion is bad. Something around 640x480. Like realy bad. The 3D objects however are in briliant quality. There must be something wrong in the settings i guess?
Scale is at "1x". 16:9 aspect is selectged but i have tryed it will al options. Even creating an own profile.
i hopw soneone knows this issue and can help.
I have tryed several aspect rations an scale.

Have you tried switching camera mode to Quality? https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/working-camera-unity

Also, note that PlayMode gives a "preview" of the AR experience, the actual camera resolution might be different once you run your actual application.
